# Excel Power Query Refresh While Co-Authoring - Can't Merge Changes

Tags: excel, powerquery, onedrive

I have a Power Query which summarizes some data on user specific sheets into a master sheet from several user specific sheets that are edited using coauthoring via one drive. The source of the query being refreshed is the workbook itself and it is refreshed by hitting the refresh button in the UI. It works fine if users are not currently editing cells but if one of the users is mid-edit in a cell and the refresh runs on the query the user is presented with a message that their changes cannot be merged and that they must discard or save a copy when they try to leave the cell. Is it possible to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I brought this issue up to MS support and was told this is likely a bug in need of a hotfix. Excel Online does not support PQ, so when PQ refreshes and co-authoring is happening, it triggers the error. Hoping an update rolls out in the near future for this because it seems like such a huge oversight.